# Would Rayleigh scattering (blue skies) be noticeable in an O'Neill cylinder?

Tags: science-based, space-constructs, light

In my story there is a full size (Island Three) O'Neill cylinder, 5 miles in diameter and 20 miles long.

It doesn't have windows, but is lit internally down the center of the cylinder with a 20 mile long, very bright, full spectrum lamp.

There is a budding artist in my story who lives there.

As imagined when she looks up the sides of the cylinder, she sees her neighbors from down the road overhead, would there be a bluish tint to their landscape which is in the distance, 3-5 miles away?

Also, if she stands at the very "north" end of the cylinder and has a clear view all the way to the "south" end, 20 miles away, would she see any blue or bluish sky due to Rayleigh scattering and the long linear "sun"?

Comment: This... is a good question... Hmmm...

Comment: One question: is the ‘sun’ also five miles away from the end caps of the cylinder or does it continue all the way to the ends? No idea if it changes the answer, but it might!

Comment: @JoeBloggs Let's say it goes all the way to the ends, though there might be ports of entry at the very ends.

Comment: [Aerial perspective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aerial_perspective) is a thing. Mountains appear blueish in the distance, say 20 km or so.

Comment: I really suspect the answer depends on the atmospheric content and the amount of particulate matter in the atmosphere. What color are the 'ends', that would stand in for the 'sky'? Or are you asking if the light from the full spectrum lamp would have some color shift as you looked at it from a distance?

Comment: The color she would see depends on two things - the sensitivity of the eye to particular colors and energies, and the absorption of the light energy as it travels. Light is not 'reflected' by an object, it is absorbed and then re-transmitted. Thus, the light she 'sees' is a combination of the wavelengths that make it through without intersecting with any particles, and the particles' ability to absorb-and-keep or absorb-and-retransmit the light energy. The human eye is most sensitive to yellow, then blue. All things equal, her eye would perceive faint blue light better than faint red light.

Comment: @JustinThyme The atmosphere is a standard earthlike atmosphere. The end caps are just steel so grey, but I am wondering about the scattering of light, yes. Much like how the sun’s light is white but the sky is blue.

Comment: So what is the 'sky' in your construction? I can envision the landscape, and the 'sun', but I don't envision what would be equivalent to 'sky' (looking into dark space through atmosphere). You have no windows.

Comment: If your end caps were transparent, looking out into space, I could envision that as looking at 'sky' through an atmosphere.

Comment: @JustinThyme “Sky” means the expanse of atmosphere within the station.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the answer's no, but I don't have time to work it all out.  Here are some good articles, the second has software that might calculate it for you.  It's complex because gravity, pressure, and composition are all involved. [On Rayleigh Optical Depth Calculations by BARRY A. BODHAINE, NORMAN B. WOOD, ELLSWORTH G. DUTTON, JAMES R. SLUSSER](http://web.gps.caltech.edu/%7Evijay/Papers/Rayleigh_Scattering/Bodhaine-etal-99.pdf) and [Simulated Rayleigh Scattering by James Nelson](https://www.byui.edu/documents/physics/Theses/James_NelsonS15.pdf)

Comment: "And purple mountains, majesty/Above the fruited plains"... Mountains appear blue(er) than things up close specifically because of raleigh scattering. I drive about 5 miles from two mountain ranges in my normal commute, and when I'm that close to a range, if it's in full sunlight, it just looks slightly hazy. If in shadow (i.e., I'm East of the range, looking West in late afternoon), then the mountains are deep blue and featureless. From personal experience, I'd put 5 miles at the barest minimum of seeing Raleigh scattering effects, but anecdote does NOT equal data.

Comment: @Ghedipunk, that's actually a good observation, but I wonder if it's scattering of the light reflected off the mountains, or caused by the scattered light from the sun that will be reflected.  I don't know enough about this effect and it's making me feel like eating ice cream and watching old episodes of Nova.

Comment: @JBH, thinking about it further...  It would have to be the reflection of pre-scattered light.  Without an atmosphere, shadows are black. It's only because of Raleigh scattering that shadows have any color at all.  I eagerly await someone with domain specific knowledge to step in.  (And eating ice cream while watching Nova sounds like an great time for me, too.)

Comment: You should be aware that O'Neill Cylinders are not dynamically stable, and thus require constant and considerable energy expenditure just to stop them from toppling end over end:

https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/2731/what-stability-issues-plague-long-artificial-gravity-cylinders

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My best guess is no.

Based on the fact that the lamp extends the entire length of the cylinder and is very bright, the light would have to travel at most the distance you are looking. On Earth, sunlight goes through miles of atmosphere, where some of the light bounces off of oxygen in the atmosphere, creating a bluish color going in all directions, some reaching your eyes a few miles away. On Earth, there is no light source over there, because all of the light comes from the sun.

If there was light on one side of the cylinder, the atmosphere might seem blue, but any blueness in a cylinder with a full-length light would be overpowered by the much stronger full-length light.

You might be able to get a blue sky effect with one light on each side, or by dimming the light, but with what you've described, the lighting would actually be harsh, like looking into the sun.